# Node.js - waiting on all Model.find() to finish

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following two Monogoose models:

```
ClanMember: tag:String, name:string;
War: members:Array; #array of tags
```

I am currently finding an array of current members by:

```
ClanMember.find({
    'tag': {
        $in: memberTags #an array of tags
    }
}).limit(memberTags.length)
  .exec(function(err, members) {

}
```

From this I want to execute `War.find()`s and add that info the each member document, so like this:

```
ClanMember.find({
    'tag': {
        $in: memberTags
    }
}).limit(memberTags.length)
    .exec(function(err, members) {

    var MemberArray = []; 
    for (var member in members) {
        if (members.hasOwnProperty(member)) {
            var currentMember = members[member];
            War.find({members: currentMember.tag}).exec(function(err, wars) {
                currentMember.wars = wars;
                MemberArray.push(currentMember);
            });
        }
    }

   #I WANT TO RENDER HERE

});
```

After this all happens, I'd like to pass the whole new array of Member objects (with War Objects) to a view:

```
    res.render('members', {
        members: MemberArray,
    });
```

What is the best way of ensuring that all War.find() functions are found and finished executing before passing the array to the render function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you have to use promises.
code should be like below.

```
var Promise = require('promise');
ClanMember.find({
    'tag': {
        $in: memberTags
    }
}).limit(memberTags.length)
    .exec(function(err, members) {
    var promises = [];
    var MemberArray = []; 
    members.forEach((member)=>{
            var currentMember = member;
            let warPromise = War.find({members: currentMember.tag}).exec().then(function(wars) {
                currentMember.wars = wars;
                MemberArray.push(currentMember);
                return true;
            }).catch(function(err){
               throw err;
            });
            promises.push(warPromise);
        }
    });


    Promise.all(promises).then(function(result){
      #I WANT TO RENDER HERE

      }).catch(function(err){

      });

});
```

Here Promise.all() function will ensure that all previous promises has been completed. And you can give response then.

Comment: please select my answer also

Comment: Thanks. This isn't quite working for me however. The `currentMember` variable within the `warPromise` is always the last `member` element from the array.. e.g. if i `console.log(currentMember.tag`)` the same tag gets returned..

Comment: I have edited my answer it will work now.. as you where using callback syntax while finding wars . I have converted it to promise. Please try it now.